# Removing noise using multi-resolution SVD

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet, bandpass-filter

I want to remove noise using multi-resolution SVD. Here is the algorithm which I want to implement that I got from a research paper.

Paper Title: **Image Denoising Using Multiresolution Singular value
Decomposition Transform.**

Authors: **Malini.Sa ,* , Moni.R.Sa**

[image: algorithm]

Here is my code:

```
imt = imread('eight.tif');
imt= im2double(imt);
imt=imresize(imt,[256,256]);
figure; imshow(imt);
J = imnoise(imt,'salt & pepper',0.1);
figure, imshow(J);
%apply MSVD
[X1, U1] = MSVD(J);
%apply IMSVD
imf = IMSVD(X1,U1);
%%%%%% MSVD %%%%
function [Y,U] = MSVD(x)
% multiresolution SVD (MSVD)
% input-> x: image (spatial domain)
% outputs-> Y: one level MSVD decomposition of x
%           U: the unitary matrix (U in SVD)
% x=imresize(x,[256,256]);
[m,n] = size(x);
m = m/2; n = n/2;
A = zeros(4,m*n);
for j = 1:n
    for i = 1:m
        A(:,i + (j-1)*m) = reshape(x((i-1)*2+(1:2),(j-1)*2+(1:2)),4,1);
    end
end
[U,S] = svd(A);
U
S
T = U'*A;
Y.LL = reshape(T(1,:),m,n);
Y.LH = reshape(T(2,:),m,n);
Y.HL = reshape(T(3,:),m,n);
Y.HH = reshape(T(4,:),m,n);
%%%% IMSVD %%%%%
function[x1] = IMSVD(Y,U)
% inverse MSVD (IMSVD)
% Inputs-> Y: MSVD coefficients & U: unitary matrix (U in SVD)
% output-> x: image (spaitial domain)
[m,n] = size(Y.LL);
mn = m*n;
T1 = zeros(4,mn);
T1(1,:) = reshape((Y.LL),1,mn);
T1(2,:) = reshape((Y.LH),1,mn);
T1(3,:) = reshape((Y.HL),1,mn);
T1(4,:) = reshape((Y.HH),1,mn);
% figure,imshow(Y.LL,[]);
A1 = U * T1;
x1 = zeros(m*2,n*2);
for j = 1:n
    for i = 1:m
        x1((i-1)*2+(1:2), (j-1)*2+(1:2)) = reshape(A1(:,i+(j-1)*m),2,2);
    end
end
figure,imshow(x1,[]);
```

My code does not work. After execution, noise still exists. Please someone modify this code so that it will remove noise.

Comment: In the algorithm, `A` is the image containing noise. Right? At the end, you *`reshape`* `A2` to get ***`A`*** back. Notice that *`A`* is the image containing noise. I don't understand how this algorithm is supposed to remove noise  if what it gives at the end is ***`A`***. Apparently, IMSVD is the inverse process of MSVD. May be all you need to apply here is MSVD. But I have no idea how it would be removing the noise

Comment: I already apply MSVD here and then apply IMSVD. But the paper states that it will remove noise in this process. Can u please check the paper.

Comment: I am not an expert of this field but the paper mentions some thresholding that I don't see in your code. Quoting from the paper you mentioned, *"The denoising strategy can
be stated as thresholding of the detailed sub bands ... Thresholding can be hard thresholding or soft thresholding ... an adaptive thresholding can also be employed."*

Comment: yes you are right, but they do it after applying msvd. but my output of MSVD also not match with them and i tried adaptive, hard and soft thresholding but , it not works.

Comment: Well I can't comment on that without seeing what you did!